# List authenticated users from Apache Shiro ServletContainerSessionManager

Tags: java, shiro

I want to implement solution for listing logged in users in Apache Shiro. I tried this code:

```
public Collection<Session> listAccounts() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        DefaultSecurityManager manager = (DefaultSecurityManager) SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager();
        DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager = (DefaultWebSessionManager) manager.getSessionManager();
        // invoke "sessionManager.getActiveSessions()" via reflection:
        Method getActiveSessionsMethod = DefaultSessionManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getActiveSessions");
        getActiveSessionsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Collection<Session> activeSessions = (Collection<Session>) getActiveSessionsMethod.invoke(sessionManager);

        return activeSessions;
    }
```

But when I run the code I get this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.ServletContainerSessionManager cannot be cast to org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
    at com.crm.web.authentication.ActiveAccounts.listAccounts(ActiveAccounts.java:22)
```

Can you give me some advice how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your call `manager.getSessionManager()` is not returning a `DefaultWebSessionManager` but a `ServletContainerSessionManager`.

`ServletContainerSessionManager` does not own the method `getActiveSessions()` so you will have to get this information another way - which really leads on the the real question of '**Why do you want to know this in the first place?**'

Comment: Can  you propose some other solution to get this information?

Comment: Conceptually what are you trying to ask?  As you have a `ServletContainerSessionManager` I'm assuming this is in a web context.  Are you trying to find out how many active users you have??

Comment: I want to list authenticated users from Apache Shiro's cache

Comment: By the wya did you managed to implement this in some of your projects?

Comment: Can you give a hand here, please?

Comment: I don't think Shiro supports this.  It will answer if the current user has authentication creds but it wont export a whole list of everything - that's a security hole for sure

Comment: I need this for monitoring purposes.

Comment: isnt there some sort on onAuth hook that you could just count?

Comment: Yes, but I will waste memory and what if session expires? Data won't be accurate.

Comment: I don't think there are any web frameworks that will give you number of concurrent sessions - primarily because these are held client side.  If you want to know the number of users currently using your service then you need some approximation derived from their call stream.

Comment: Can you give some example for Java Server Faces? What do you mean by ` approximation derived from their call stream`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111944/discussion-between-lee-and-peter-penzov).